# clicking the button in the alert box or overriding the window.alert()?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application window where I'am required to press a button to remove some stuff many times (the button is easily click-able with JS by selecting it with getElementbyClassName()[i]). But after each click I have to manually press the "OK" button on the window.alert("Are you sure?"); box.

I can't change the websites mechanism as I'm not the owner or developer. But I want somehow to be able to automate this stuff.

JS I use for clicking on the element:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ruleAddButton');
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].click();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since alert is only to show info to the user (you can't get user input from an alert), I think you maybe want to monkey patch **confirm** function this way:

```
var originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function(msg) {
  if (msg.match(/Are you sure/) {
    // this confirm should return always true
    return true;
  } else {
    // we want other confirms works as normal
    return originalConfirm.bind(window)(msg);
  }
}
```

Just in case, I would do the same trick for alert function

```
var originalAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {
  if (msg.match(/Are you sure/) {
    // this is what alert always returns after user clicks OK
    return undefined;
  } else {
    // we want other alerts works as normal
    return originalAlert.bind(window)(msg);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, you can do something as simple as:

```
window.confirm = function() { return true; };
```

But on this case, be aware that **ALL** confirm calls will be intercepted

Comment: would the same hold for window.confirm = function() {
    return true;
};

??

Comment: Yes, (I will add it to the answer), but be aware if you use window.confirm = function() { return true; }; ALL confirms on the page always will return true, if it is ok for you , then it is the simplest way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can't click the OK button in a dialog created by `window.alert`. That dialog is created by the browser and is not controllable from the webpage's JavaScript context. However, what you *can* do is just monkey-patch the `alert` function to not show a dialog at all:

```
window.alert = function() {
    // Do nothing.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the alert function:

```
window.alert = function(){}
```

But it will disable all alerts on this page.